# Not able to patch datetime.utcnow in a custom type based on Pydantic's BaseModel

Tags: python, pytest, pydantic

I am not able to patch `datetime.utcnow` correctly and I am wondering what could be wrong. The code below illustrates the idea:

```
# In a file called 'my_module.py'
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Pet(BaseModel):
    ts: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
```

And the corresponding test code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
from unittest.mock import patch
from my_module import Pet

@patch("my_module.datetime")
def test_pet(mocked):
    timestamp = datetime(2000, 10, 10, 21, 50)
    mocked.utcnow.return_value = timestamp
    pet = Pet()
    assert pet.ts == timestamp
    # pet.ts is getting current date and time :/
```

When I run `pytest`, the `pet.ts` does not get assigned the patched timestamp. Instead it is getting the current date and time. I am wondering what could be wrong/missing in my setup. Would anyone have an idea?

I am using the following tools:

```
Python   3.9.8
pydantic 1.9.0
pytest   6.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but as a workaround:

```py
    ts: datetime = Field(default_factory=lambda: datetime.utcnow())
```

The problem is that in your snippet `datetime.utcnow` is bound when `from my_module import Pet`, which occurs before the `patch`.

By making it a `lambda` the binding is deferred to instance creation.